# GCP terraform provider - possible documentation bug?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

The documentation for [google_compute_subnetwork > private_ip_google_access](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/d/datasource_compute_subnetwork.html#private_ip_google_access) states that private_ip_google_access is an exported attribute as opposed to being an argument which I assume means that it cannot be specified in my terraform code. However, I have just run a successful `terraform apply` using this terraform HCL code:

```
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnetwork" {
  name                     = "${var.subnetname}"
  ip_cidr_range            = "${var.subnet_range}"
  network                  = "${var.network}"
  region                   = "${var.region}"
  private_ip_google_access = "true"
}
```

So one of the following must be true:
* I am misunderstanding what it means to be an attribute. My assumption up to now has been that arguments can be specified, attributes cannot. Am I wrong in this assumption?
* The documentation incorrectly states that `private_ip_google_access` is an attribute whereas actually it should be an argument.

Which of those is true?

Comment: The documentation you have linked to here is for a `data "google_compute_subnetwork"` block, but your configuration is a `resource "google_compute_subnetwork"` block. The relevant documentation for the `resource` block contents is here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_subnetwork.html

Comment: You are correct, and now I feel suitably embarrassed. Sorry for wasting folks’ time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in both cases.

A resource has two sets of elements, arguments for input and attribute for output.

In this case, as you are able to set `private_ip_google_access` when calling the resource, it means that it's actually an argument and not an attribute.

Comment: Looks like the docs source is already correct https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/blob/master/website/docs/r/compute_subnetwork.html.markdown, just hasn't been updated at https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/d/datasource_compute_subnetwork.html yet which is kinda worrying but heigh-ho.